# Java: Add Decorating class to existing implementation

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, decorator

Currently I have the following setup (to keep it small I did not post all annotations):

```
public class MessageRestService {

  private MessageService messageService;

  MessageRestService(MessageService messageService) {
    this.messageService = messageService;
  }

  @GetMapping
  public Response getAllMessages() {
    return messageService.getAllMessages();
  }
}


public interface MessageService {

 String getAllMessages();

}

public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService {

  @Override
  public String getAllMessages() {
    ...
    return messageDao.getAllMessages();
  }

}
```

Now I'm trying to add a decorator class to this implementation, where before the call additional things can be done (e.g. access check or logging,...).

Therefore I tried to create a decorator class which can do f.ex. logging, before the actual implementation gets called.

```
@Singleton
public class MessageDecorator implements MessageService {
  @Inject
  private final MessageService messageService;

  @Override
  public String getAllMessages() {
    // here we can log
    return messageService.getAllMessages();
  }
}
```

The project is compiling without problems, but calling the getAllMessages() method, the decorator does not get called, the process (works) as before, but without logging anything.

I'm honestly stuck, I have seen once a working example of this, but I do not remember exactly anymore what was different to my approach or where I did a mistake / forgot to change something.